# Match consecutive lines in a file.

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, grep

```
template: perm_subcluster
   copy_cluster: yms_cfg_ref
   allocations:
   - type: cfgstore
     hosts:
     - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: aggregator
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsagg-08.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsagg-10.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: metricsdb
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
```

The above code belongs to the file temp.txt. 
Another file tempo.pl has a perl scalar variable $pattern.
The value of $pattern is:

```
- type: cfgstore
  hosts:
  - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
  - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
- type: aggregator
  hosts:
  - {name: ymsagg-08.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
  - {name: ymsagg-10.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
- type: metricsdb
  hosts:
  - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
  - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
```

I want to write a block of code in perl or sed or awk or regex which returns me the template name i.e 
template: perm_subcluster
If the value of $pattern matches with the block of lines in temp.txt.

Comment: Can you confirm that the data is actually stored in YAML format? Then, it would be best to parse the data into a data structure, and look where the template data structure contains the pattern. Or does it *have* to be regexes? (not impossible, just incredibly buggy).

Comment: what is `matches`: `= equal`  or `~ matches` ?

Comment: Are the leading spaces equal in `$pattern` and `temp.txt`? Or at least do `$pattern` and `temp.txt` always differ by 3 spaces? And does the block always start exactly three lines after `template:`?

Comment: @amon - Yes the data is stored in YAML format, but the YAML file is very garbled so i decided not to parse and instead search for pattern to obtain the name of template.

Comment: @m.buettner - Yes the block always starts exactly three lines after template. Also the leading spaces in variable $pattern can be made to match the leading space in file, same since i am framing the variable $pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Description

You'll have to modify the "what I'm searching for" block to contain all the same leading spaces as exist in the target data.

Your search for text will need to be inserted into this expression between the `\Q`...`\E` tags. The expression will then find the template name for the block of text you've selected, the name will be placed into Capture Group 1.

```
^template:\s*(\S*).*?(?=^)(?:^\s+(?:(?!^).)*)*?^\Q   - type: cfgstore
     hosts:
     - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: aggregator
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsagg-08.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsagg-10.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: metricsdb
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}\E
```

**Input Text**

```
template: perm_subcluster
   copy_cluster: yms_cfg_ref
   allocations:
   - type: cfgstore
     hosts:
     - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: aggregator
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsagg-08.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsagg-10.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: metricsdb
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
template: Not_me
   copy_cluster: yms_cfg_ref
   allocations:
   - type: cfgstore
     hosts:
     - {name: Fail_ymscfg-02.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: Fail_ymscfg-02.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: aggregator
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsagg-08.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsagg-10.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: metricsdb
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
```

**Matches**

```
[0] => template: perm_subcluster
   copy_cluster: yms_cfg_ref
   allocations:
   - type: cfgstore
     hosts:
     - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymscfg-02.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: aggregator
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsagg-08.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsagg-10.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
   - type: metricsdb
     hosts:
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.bf1.yahoo.com, farm: east}
     - {name: ymsdb-11.ops.gq1.yahoo.com, farm: west}
[1] => perm_subcluster
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Unix-style end-of-line:

```
$temp_txt =~ /template:\s*(.*)\n(\s.*\n)*?\Q$pattern/;
return $1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk, for example when looking for `ymsagg-08` you could try:

```
awk '$1=="template:"{t=$2} $0~s{print t}' s="ymsagg-08" file
```